# ¿Como hago que la altura de un elemento sea adapte a un %?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, web

mi duda es como podría hacer para que un elemento(en especifico un `<div>`) se adapte a un x% de altura de la pantalla, para que así independientemente del equipo donde se vea tenga el mismo efecto, algo asi como lo de la siguiente imagen

[image: img]

***El código que pensé(El cual no tuvo el efecto que pensaba) era este:***

```css
html, body{
 background-color: #1C1C1C;
}

div{
 color: #FF00FF;
 border-color: red;
 border-style: solid;
 height: 800%;
 width: 60%:;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div>
    <p>
                   <i>contenido</i>
    </p>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**Gracias**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso existe algo llamado **Unidades de viewport** que son relativas a la pantalla donde se estén ejecutando, entre las más reconocidas están las medidas `vw` (viewport width) y `vh` (viewport height) que reemplazan en este caso las medidas `%` (porcentaje).

[Documentación de las unidades de viewport](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

div {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 60vw;
  margin: 10vh auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>Flotante</div>
```

Comment: Eso era exactamente lo que buscaba, aunque igual me queda la intriga de si se podrá lograr algo así manejando porcentajes; Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Puede que se logre realizar con porcentajes, pero ellos se modifican respecto a la caja contenedora de donde se apliquen, por lo que no aplica efectivamente a lo expuesto en la pregunta, pues la caja contenedora del DIV podría variar, se podría intentar, se tendría que hacer uso de un `position: fixed` y cosas de ese estilo para lograr el mismo resultado.

Comment: entiendo, gracias por la explicación